# Saving the form data and using said form data to redirect to a proper URL

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

thanks to the help and valuable insight from Stack Overflow members, I am very close to finishing my quiz project. I do, however, have a few more questions in regards to the finishing touches of the project. Before I start, I want to give a brief background on my quiz project.

The quiz consists of 10 questions. Each question is either a multiple choice or Y/N that simply uses radio buttons and an answer button that submits the information. The code incorporates both JavaScript and PHP, and maybe some Ajax later on. What it can do so far (if followed precisely) is that when the user enters the first page to answer the first question, selects a radio button and hits the answer button, it submits the form and prints the appropriate text depending on whether it was correct or incorrect. This part works well, at least for me at the moment.

What doesn't work well are two things. I'm able to increment and even show the incremented value on the page (though it won't show up in the final iteration) but when the page is refreshed, you can go through the same process again in the first page and increment the total correct variable. This means that, as the user, you can increment the total correct variable without even leaving the first question (not at all good).

This is my code here:

```
foreach ($correctAns as $key => $answer)
{
    if (!empty($_POST[$key]))
    {
        if ($_POST[$key] == $answer)
        {
            print $correct[$index];
            $_SESSION["totalCorrect"]++;
            print $_SESSION["totalCorrect"]; 
        }
        else if($_POST[$key] != $answer)
        {
            print $incorrect[$index];
            print "0";
        }
    }
    $index++;
};
```

The goal is to increment the total correct variable from each page and based on how many were correct, take them to one of two pages. For example, if their total correct variable was less than 7, then they are redirect to a retake page. If it was equal to or more than 7, then they are taken to the success page.

Here is an example of the form submission:

```
<form>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Question 1</legend>
            <input type="radio" name="answer1" value="a" id="1a"><label for="1a" >  A.</label>
            <br>
            <input type="radio" name="answer1" value="b" id="1b"><label for="1b">  B.</label>
            <br>
            <input type="radio" name="answer1" value="c" id="1c"><label for="1c">  C.</label>
            <br>
            <input type="radio" name="answer1" value="d" id="1d"><label for="1d">  D.</label>
    </fieldset>
            <input type="button" id="answer" class="" value="ANSWER">
</form>
```

The main thing I want to lock down is that when the user has selected a radio button and clicked on the answer button, that value is stored on my PHP file. If the user has 3 correct answers so far, it should keep those 3 correct answers. It will all be evaluated when the user answers all 10 questions after clicking on the submit button on the question 10.

I've looked into destroying form data for a session and using another PHP file to redirect, but I'm still confused on some areas. For example, if the user is on question 4 and decides for whatever reason to refresh the page, does the form data from questions 1-3 get destroyed as well?

Let me know if there's anything else I can provide or clarify.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are using a session, simly use a session variable to save the reached question, and another session to save the counter of correct answer.

Then in the header of each page, check by PHP script which question does the user reached.

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!$_SESSION['question_id']){
$_SESSION['question_id'] = 1;
$_SESSION['correct_answers'] = 0;
}

$question_id = $_SESSION['question_id'];

// select question where question_id = $question_id 
// select all choices and correct answer ($correct_answer)
// print the question with the choices 

if(isset $_post['submit']){
if($correct_answer == $_POST['choice']){
$_SESSION['correct_answers']+=1;
$_SESSION['question_id']+=1;
}
}
```

Comment: So maybe something like this: $_SESSION['answer1'] == $ans1. Should it be the id of the form that's saved?

Comment: The ID of the form that's saved will be incremented on each submit, starting by 1 as the first question, and when the user submit a question and you checked for the answer, then you can add 1 to the session.